# Sharepoint real time notifications of activity

Tags: c#, azure, logging, sharepoint

I want to integrate Azure with Sharepoint, to send real time notifications of my customers' activities on Sharepoint. I want my system email Id to get notifications about it.

Comment: Welcome Chris. You not raise a question. Do you want to dend an email by C# or as an API call over Sharepoint

Comment: Do you want emails to be sent for a specific library ? Ca n you please elaborate your requirement